# For Loops that append based on negative indices - Javascrip

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, append

**Goal**: write a loop that appends the sum of the last two items in [fib] to the end of [fib] for 20 loops and find the values of the last iteration.

**Code Thus Far**

```
let fib = [0,1]

let accumulator = 0

for (t=0;t<20;t++){
  endingDigits = fib[-1]+ fib[-2];
  accumulator =+ Number(accumulator) + Number(endingDigits);
  fib.push(endingDigits);
  t++;
}
console.log(fib)
```

**Results**
I keep getting NaN - Which is why Rap the two negative indices in the number method.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `=+` that looks like a typo already. You also have a `t++` at the end, even though the loop already increments `t`.

Comment: `fib[-1]` will in this case always be `undefined`. The `-1` index does **not** mean "one index from the end of the array".